# How do I return the featured image on the most recent post made in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a "Pic of the Week" feature on my homepage. I set it up so I created a post category "Pic of the Week" and I will make a post and add the pic as the featured image. I'm looking for the PHP to return the last featured image on the last post that was made in a specific category.

I'm really not sure where to start for this so I apologize for not putting what I've tried. So far I've found

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this (get the last post by `category name` ad then get the featured image using it's `id`)

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'Pic of the Week',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc'
);

$post = get_posts( $args );
if($post) {
    $post_id = $post[0]->ID;
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)){
        // use one of these
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail');
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(80, 80), array('class' => 'post_thumbnail') );
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! Know how where I can specify the size dimensions of the image in that code?

Comment: Welcome and this `array(80, 80)` is for dimension.

Comment: Hmm for some reason the pic is huge - like almost taking up the entire page. I changed the dimensions lower but I don't think that's the problem. I moved it around in the code just to avoid being in certain divs but it's huge. Any ideas?

Comment: Try without `array('class' => 'post_thumbnail')`.

Comment: Same thing =\ Maybe I'll try in a different file

Comment: YOU SHOULD CHECK [Post_Thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Add_New_Post_Thumbnail_Sizes) to add a custom size and other things.

Comment: The code works fine - I put it in another page and it's showing up normally. It's just making the pic huge in the page I have it in right now for some reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would get the postID using the [get recent posts function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts):

```
wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output )
```

This will allow you to get the post ID. You can then use the follow to get the image.

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
```

Comment: `OP` wants to get the thumbnail of recent post under `Pic of the Week` category.

Comment: That is what $args is for in wp_get_recent_posts. The selected answer above is fairly similar to my answer.